# Problem in Creating Simple Form in Zend

Tags: zend-form

I am new on Zend Framwork(MVC). I want to crate simple a Form with some HTML control.

I have create one controller IndexController, code are as follows:

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // action body

        /*$this->view->var = 'User Login Page';*/
        $form = new Form_Login();

        $this->view->form=$form;
    }
}
```

And my Form's code in application/forms/Login.php:

```
<?php

require_once('Zend/Form.php');
class Form_Login extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::__construct($options);

        // the code bellow will create element
        $username = $this->CreateElement('text','username');
        $username->setLabel("Username:");

        // and
        $submit= $this->CreateElement("submit","submit");
        $submit->setLabel("Submit");

        // now add elements to the form as
        $this->addElements(array(
            $username,
            $submit
        ));
    }
}

?>
```

When i run this project then its show an error like this:

```
**Fatal error: Class 'Form_Login' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\LoginForm\application\controllers\IndexController.php on line 16**
```

Please help me...

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good, make sure your Login.php file has this as the first lines:

```
<?php
class Form_Login extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
```

If that doesn't help, you might want to check your index.php/Bootstrap.php files and server configuration to make sure all paths are correct.